# How to round up 1.4549999999999998 using BigDecimal ROUND_HALF_UP?

Tags: groovy, rounding, bigdecimal

I need to round numbers like 1.4549999999999998 up to 1.46.  I am writing in Groovy and have the following method.

```
 def roundBigDecimal(bd_val, scale, roundingMode) {
     assert bd_val instanceof BigDecimal
     return new BigDecimal(bd_val).setScale(scale, roundingMode)
}
```

However, when I try:
    roundBigDecimal(1.4549999999999998, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP), I get back 1.45.

Comment: Yes, you get 1.45 because 1.454999 is BELOW 1.455, so there is no "half" to round up. You probably want ROUND_UP. Or do it in two steps: set scale to 3 first, to get 1.455 and then round that again to scale 2.

Answer (score 1):

From [BigDecimal docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP):

> ROUND_HALF_UP
>
> @Deprecated(since="9")
>
> Use RoundingMode.HALF_UP instead.

This method is deprecated since Java 9, solution is to call `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` method:

```
roundBigDecimal(1.4549999999999998, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

Comment: Nope, it should return 1.46 as 1.455 is rounded to 1.46

Comment: Did you try that? Because 1.454999etc. is **less than "half", so it will not be rounded up**. Try it. In Java: `BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1.4549999999999998").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` **prints as `1.45`** as I expected. The rounding does not scale step by step, it scales directly, and 1.45499999 is below 1.455 and thus will not round up, when you use HALF_UP.

Comment: In other words: yes, 1.455 is rounded to 1.46, but 1.45499...8. is not!

Comment: From JavaDoc "Note that this is the rounding mode commonly taught at school." so that is pretty misleading info... I wasn't taught this rounding behavior for sure :D

Comment: But I was, in the Netherlands. So 1.4546666 was not rounded up, even if you could round 1.4546666 to 1.454667, then 1.45467, 1.4547, 1.455 and finally 1.46 etc.

Comment: I think that it's rather not a scientific approach, but I can imagine that definition is not the same in various countries. They shouldn't write something like that in the docs...

Comment: I think it is the correct approach. Only exactly halfway, it should round up. Otherwise it should depend on the actual value. The docs say: `HALF_UP -- Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.`. Well, only exactly 1.455 (or 1.4550...) are equidistant. 1.454999... is closer to 1.45 than to 1.46. That makes more sense than to round e.g. 1.4546666 up to 1.46, since 1.4546666 is much closer to 1.45 than to 1.46.

Answer (score 0):

I would go one step back:
Whenever you have such an issue, it's a signal that you have lost precision already earlier on the way.
I highly recommend to fix it at the root, so you will not even receive such numbers.
E.g. conversion double to string then to BigDecimal, or deserialization handling of such values, if they still have been precise during transport.

Several frameworks (e.g. Jackson) just map numbers numb to double if you do not care. You should already force such frameworks to directly go towards BigDecimal. They usually provide everything out of the box, just need to care about.